# How do you allocate an array in a parallel numba function?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numba

I'd like to be able to allocate a numpy array inside a parallel numba routine, but it seems that the threads can't see a newly-allocated array.

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def myfun(n,mat=None):
    if mat is None:
        mat=np.empty(n)
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        mat[i]=i
    return mat

n=1000
mat=np.empty(n)
mat2=myfun(n,mat) #filling array works in parallel                                                           
mat3=myfun(n)  #breaks
```

Everything works as expected if I allocate the array outside of the function.  If I allocate inside the function, it also works with parallel=False, or use np.arange instead of nb.prange.  However, the code as-written breaks when I try to allocate inside the function, with array out-of-bound errors. Presumably the threads are trying to write to None instead of seeing the allocated version of mat.  Coming from OpenMP, I assumed the code was serial until it got to the prange and that there's an implicit barrier at the start of the parallel loop.  At least one of those assumptions seems to be wrong, though, and I haven't been able to find documentation on what's actually happening under the hood.

Comment: It seems to work properly on my machine with Numba 0.57.0 on my machine (on Windows). I got no errors and results seems fine without any crash. Can you try with a recent version of Numba? AFAIR, optional parameters was quite buggy in older version of Numba.

Comment: That worked, thanks!  I was running 0.56.4 so looks like the bug only got fixed quite recently.